Checkbox troubles with HML Conditional IF statement in Lightning Template
I'm struggling with trying to get an HML conditional IF statement to properly recognize the values of checkbox field in Lightning Email templates.
For example, I'm trying to create an IF statement that returns different results based on whether a checkbox has been checked:
{{#if Page.Passed__c}}
Status: Passed
{{else}}
Status: Failed
{{/if}}

However, no matter what the state of the checkbox is, the IF statement always recognizes it as checked and displays "Status: Passed" whether it is checked or not.
When I check the field value in the same template:
{{{Page.Passed__c}}}

It returns either 1 or 0 depending on if the checkbox is checked or not.
When I do a query in Developer Console the value properly reflects "true" or "false" depending on whether the checkbox is checked or not.
Is anyone familiar with what the issue may be here and any possible fixes or work arounds?
